# Is there a reputation league based on softwares badges?

Tags: support, reputation

I would like to know if there is a reputation league based on "software badges" (ex. [python],[java]) and possibly how to get there.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on any tag, then click "top users".  For example, [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers).

There is no general rep leagues for sets of tags, since that would require explicitly categorizing all tags.  And it wouldn't work anyways since questions are mis-tagged and something like `C#` could used on a question about the language, or a question about a program in C#, or a question about the compiler, and so on.

Of course, in a broad sense *all* of Stack Overflow is about software, so you can just look at the general [all-time rep league](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i was looking for.

Comment: Errgh, per-badge top-user pages are *ugly*.